# How can I force the horizontal constraints on a widget to get priority over its vertical constraints?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I need to build a square that always spreads over the entire width of the screen (portrait orientation), whatever the size of the screen. Below this square and some fixed height widgets, I want to allocate the remaining available space to a text field.

The simplified code below shows what I have tried so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ScMainFull"
>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/Grid"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread_inside"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button1"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:text="1"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Grid"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/Report"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Report"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

On the vertical axis, the available space (total height less vertical margins and fixed height button) is evenly distributed between the two widgets that have `layout_height="0dp"` ignoring the horizontal constraints in the first widget.

What should I change in this code to have the space allocated to the textview calculated after the square has been built to occupy the full width of the screen? Another way to ask the same question would be: how can I force the horizontal constraints on the square to get priority over its vertical constraints?

Comment: Are you forced to use ConstraintLayout? Otherwise you could achieve what you want using a vertical LinearLayout.

Comment: Yes the parent must be a ConstraintLayout. This allows me to use the `layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"` to easily get a square. Other views not shown in the simplified code above also require the parent to be a ConstraintLayout.
The square view can be any type of widget. I have tried with a `View` but the problem is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the squared top `ConstraintLayout` from the chain.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/Grid"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:text="1"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Grid"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/Report"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Report"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

You are doing it wrong if you are thinking about nesting another ViewGroup.